# Open webview form and get result back to app

Tags: android, html, post, android-webview, response

I'm developing an Android application that allow the customers to make payments using a payment gateway.

In the final step I open a webview so that the user can see the payment gateway as it gives more confidence than introducing credit card details in the application.

The user introduces the payment details in the webview and clicks a button to confirm. Then the website redirects the user to another URL showing success or error.

I'd like to be able to know in the application if the payment successed or not so I can close the webview and show an error/success message. I know that the HTML of the redirected URL hold this data but I cannot figure out how to retrieve it in my application.

Any idea regarding this issue?

Comment: You can try to override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` of `WebViewClient`, which you need to set in your WebView

Comment: do you have access to the webpage code

Comment: It's a third party website used to make payments. I'm not the owner